# Xpath clicking button within a td where row contains a specific text vlaue

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath

I'm currently using Nightwatch to do some automated tests, but CSS selectors were extremely complex and did not do the job for me.  I've instead started to look at XPath to do the job however the table in question is fairly complex.

I want to be able to .click() a button within a td value, where that specific row in the table contains a specific value.  The table looks like this:

```
Username    Email           Display Name    Buttons to Click (1st one wanted)
test        test@example    test            (1st button)(2nd button)
test2       test2@example   test            (1st button)(2nd button)
```

Each of these values are within a tr > td so being able to find it is proving difficult.  This is my currently XPath:

```
.click('/table[@id="admin-user-list"]/tbody/tr[td = "test2"]/td/button')
```

The HTML tree looks like this:

```
<div id>
    <div class>
       <table class>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td data-bind>(username)
                   <td data-bind>(email)
                   <td data-bind>(display name)
                   <td button>
                       (1st button)
                       (2nd button)
               </tr>
           </tbody>
```

Each row has its own tr with those exact tds inside.

Some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Share `HTML` code for the same

Comment: I cannot give the code itself, but I will give a tree of how it is laid out.

Comment: You shouldn't use `tbody` tag in your `XPath`. Try `'//td[.="test2"]/button'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.click('//table[@id="admin-user-list"]/tbody/tr[./td[text()='test2']/td/button')
```

> logic:  `//table[@id="admin-user-list"]/tbody/tr[./td[text()='test2']`
>   - tr with td that has text
>
> `/td/button` -button in that row

but actually this is not really good idea to do that, as you are searching for that value in each column. Better to use combination of columnName+value

Let's check on that table sample: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

We'll search for table data in column by name, for example table `column = Country, data = UK`

```
//*[@id='customers']//tr/td[count(//*[@id='customers']//th[text()='Country']/preceding-sibling::*)+1][text()='UK']
```

again, logic is simple: 
general locator is:
`//*[@id='customers']//tr/td` - we are searching for table data
with parameters: `[text()='UK']` and position = same, as in column name `[count(column_position)]`

How to get column position:
just get column with needed text:

`//*[@id='customers']//th[text()='Country']` and count it's preceding siblings: 
`//*[@id='customers']//th[text()='Country']/preceding-sibling::*` , also we should add +1 , as we need current element's position. and count that staff, so here is the result: `[count(//*[@id='customers']//th[text()='Country']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]`

so having column position we can get general locator:

> tableId = customers; columnName= Country; dataText =  UK;
>
> `//*[@id='tableId']//tr/td[count(//*[@id='tableId']//th[text()='columnName']/preceding-sibling::*)+1][text()='dataText']`

And here is locator to get hole row by data+columnName

```
//*[@id='customers']//tr[./td[count(//*[@id='customers']//th[text()='Country']/preceding-sibling::*)+1][text()='UK']]
```

and basically you can search anything inside of it, for example just add in the end
`/td/button` - to get button from it